# How could I integrate a custom trained PyTorch model in dnn module in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, onnx

I have a model, trained in PyTorch. I want to integrate it with dnn module in opencv so that trained model could be easily used. 
Actually, I have a model and planning to contribute it in opencv. I am not getting how to make my model so that it can be accessed through opencv dnn module, like models already defined in opencv.

Do I need to use ONNX to load model in dnn?

In short, I have a pytorch model, I want to contribute to OpenCV by adding my model there like other predefined models.

A small guide would be helpful.

Thanks in advance...